# Azure Azcopy - cron jobs

Tags: cron

We have Azure Azcopy configured on Ubuntu Server (16.04). The ini file we have created pulls data from a cloud storage account to the local Ubuntu system within Azure. When we run it manually, there are no issues.

However, we want to run it via a cron job every thirty minutes.

Here are the steps we have taken (we've tried variants from stack flow postings as well). Cron is running.

```
crontab -e

30 * * * * root /azcopy/azcopy --config-file "azcopy_run.ini"
```

- `crontab -l` lists it fine
- no errors in logging

Any guidance please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

run "crontab -e" as root  (eg. with sudo), and enter

```
30 * * * * /azcopy/azcopy --config-file "azcopy_run.ini"
```

With good old standard cron, you don't specify a user.

But I find it hard to believe there are no errors.  Cron usually mails them to the user that ran "crontab -e".